# Can no longer see Route 53 Hosted Zone?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a hosted zone and the accompanying record sets defined to serve a domain which lives in GoDaddy. I went to the AWS console today and found my hosted zone is no longer listed. However, it is still working and routing to my AWS server instance. Has anyone else see this issue in AWS? Any advice for finding my missing, yet working, hosted zone definition?

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the account you use. Asking on AWS' own forums may get you some help from the employees.